# How to increase PNotify font size?

Tags: css, pnotify

What's the best way to increase font size of PNotify notifications ?

```
new PNotify({
  title: "Title",
  text: "Some information more.",
  type: "notice"
})
```

From [here](https://sciactive.github.io/pnotify/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any built-in way to do that. You should add `addclass: "someClass"` to the initialization and then change the font size by writing `.someClass .ui-pnotify-text { font-size: 1.25em }` for the description text and `.someClass .ui-pnotify-title { font-size: 1.25em }` for the title into your custom CSS file.